# Make every link on my blog open in another window with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

With the mighty aid of the jQuery library, how can I have every link on my blog open in another window?

Instead of putting `target="_blank"` on every link, is there a way I can shortcut this with the use of jQuery?

Comment: Also, your question is hazy. It could be interpreted as "have every link open in another window *at the same time*". Also you're not saying what kind of new window you want. Please add more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need jQuery

insert this to your `<header>`

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

see more: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp

Comment: @Radu No it's not, check this out http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-attributes

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware they're adding it back in HTML5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, I guess you could do something like this:

```
$('a.newWindow').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(href.length > 0) {
       window.open(href);
    }
});
```

Or, just do it the **right way**:

```
$('a.newWindow').attr('target', '_blank');
```